# hello world в svn - занести в ignore лист все файлы Makefile.am

Tags: svn

Пытаюсь занести в `ignore` лист все файлы `Makefile.am` (один находится в корне проекта, а другой в `src`). Что делаю не так?

```
$ svn status
?       configure.in
?       src
?       Makefile.am

$ svn propset svn:ignore 'Makefile.am' .
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'

$ svn status 
M      .
?       configure.in
?       src

$ svn add --force .
A         src
A         src/main.c
A         src/Makefile.am
A         configure.in

$ svn status 
M      .
A       configure.in
A       src
A       src/main.c
A       src/Makefile.am
```

Тот который в корне норм попадает в `ignore` лист, а тот который в `src` почему то нет.

Честно искал в `google` прежде чем тут задать вопрос. С `svn` не разу до этого не имел дела.

Видел такие решения в гугле почему то они тоже не пашут:

```
$ svn propset svn:ignore 'Makefile.am' . --recursive
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'

$ svn status 
M      .
?       configure.in
?       src

$ svn pg -R svn:ignore .
. - Makefile.am

$ svn add --force .
A         src
A         src/main.c
A         src/Makefile.am
A         configure.in

$ svn status 
M      .
A       configure.in
A       src
A       src/main.c
A       src/Makefile.am

$ svn pg -R svn:ignore .
. - Makefile.am
```

или так

```
$ svn propset svn:global-ignores 'Makefile.am' .
property 'svn:global-ignores' set on '.'

$ svn status 
M      .
?       configure.in
?       src
?       Makefile.am

$ svn add --force .
A         src
A         src/main.c
A         src/Makefile.am
A         configure.in
A         Makefile.am

$ svn status 
M      .
A       configure.in
A       src
A       src/main.c
A       src/Makefile.am
A       Makefile.am
```

**Обновление**

1. Создал на сервере через RapidSVN папочку проекта.
2. Сделал через `RapidSVN` чекаут этой папки поверх локальной папки
3. В локальной папке через командную строку выполнил то что вы посоветовали.
4. К сожалению, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: где вы запускаете svn propset svn:global-ignores 'Makefile.am' . ? что то изменилось или как?

Answer (score 1):

думаю поможет этот вариант

```
$ svn propset svn:global-ignores 'Makefile.am' .
```

или этот в зависимости версии `svn`

```
$ svn propset svn:ignore 'Makefile.am' . --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

> Что делаю не так?

- "Поспешность нужна только при ловле блох"
- Про ключ `--force` во всех командах SVN рекомендую забыть наглухо

Пока src не часть репозитория (`? src`), SVN ничего и никак не может сделать с его содержимым (его просто нет), ну и все родительские `svn:ignore`|`svn:global-ignores` на /src **просто не работают**

Варианты решения (от более простого к более геморройному)

- Сначала создать пустое дерево проекта, прописать игнор-лист (в корне - нормально для 1.8 с наследованием), добавить `svn add src` (все еще пустой) `/src`), после этого перенести все файлы на законное место в src

Получается примерно так

```
>dir /B /S
z:\WC2\src
z:\WC2\Makefile.am
z:\WC2\configure.in

>svn pl -v
Properties on '.':
  svn:global-ignores
    Makefile.am

>svn st --no-ignore
 M      .
I       Makefile.am
?       configure.in
?       src
```

(единственный `M` из-за propset)

```
>svn add src
A         src
```

В `/src` как *уже в части репо* наследуется игнор-лист

```
src>svn pl --show-inherited-props
Inherited properties on '.',
from 'Z:\WC2':
  svn:global-ignores
```

и после копирования в него отложенных до того файлов

```
>svn st --no-ignore
 M      .
I       Makefile.am
?       configure.in
A       src
I       src\Makefile.am
?       src\main.c
```

- Если пустое дерево не получается/лениво/есть возможность наколбасить, то процесс практически такой же, с единственным отличием - при `svn add src` надо помнить, что add рекурсивен до упора, и чтобы он не добавил лишнего, добавляем только /src, без содержимого (после добавления игнор-лист подхватится и будет легче) - это ключ `--depth 'empty'`
- Универсальный, но неудобный для работы руками вариант. У svn add есть ключик `--targets`, параметр которого - файл со списком всех дополнительных файлов (и вообще *объектов*), которые нужно добавить в дополнение к поименованным в командной строке.

Из dir|ls

```
z:\WC2\src
z:\WC2\Makefile.am
z:\WC2\configure.in
z:\WC2\.svn\pristine
z:\WC2\.svn\tmp
z:\WC2\.svn\wc.db
z:\WC2\.svn\entries
z:\WC2\.svn\format
z:\WC2\src\Makefile.am
z:\WC2\src\main.c
```

достаточно легко получить (убиранием ненужного)

```
configure.in
src\main.c
```